# Changing the value attribute of an item in a select2 following an AJAX db insert

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm adding a new item to a select2. When this happens I'm triggers an onChange AJAX request. The AJAX request adds the new item to a DB and returns the id of the row that has been inserted.

ATM, the value of the added option in the select2 contains the original string value that I entered. I want to update the value of that specific option in the select2, so that it becomes the id of the database row that was returned from the AJAX call.

Here's the JS:

```
$('.my-select2').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/groups/saveGroup',
        data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            "value": this.value
        },
        dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){

            console.log(data); // this equals the id of the row in the db, 
                               // and it's what I want to make into the value of 
                               // the option that's been added.

            // I've tried many more than the following and none have worked.

            // $(this).attr("value", data);
            // $(this).val(data).change();
            // $(this).select2("val", data);
            // $('.my-select2').select2('data', {id: data, text: 'original value'});
        }       
    });
```

Please help, I'm out of ideas, and out of Google searches.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by having a separate AJAX function outside of this, which retrieved all of the records from the db and re-painted the entire select2 control. It's a little more expensive, but does the job.